# Driving a 5V IR led with a 5V charger?

Tags: led, infrared, current-limiting

I'm trying to build a remote control with IR led.
I'm experiencing low range with my 1.5V, If=50mA IR leds, so I looked for and found a [5V, If=100mA IR leds](http://www.vishay.com/docs/81011/tsal6400.pdf).
twice the current, hence probably better transmission capabilities.
The problem is, I'm not sure what to do about the current limiting resistor.
I know that its important to limit the current so that the led wont burnt, 
and so with the 1.5V led I used a 35 Ohm resistor.
But now voltage drop is not needed, because the source is the same as the consumer.
Do I still need to worry about current limiting resistor or do I simply plug it directly?

Comment: Links? Vf is a current and not a voltage?

Comment: @Dave A typo, sorry. I updated the main question with the link to the spreadsheet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've misread the datasheet. The reverse voltage is 5V (which is not uncommon for small LEDs), but the forward voltage is 1.6V. You will still need a current limiter.